# How to put the text at the center of inner div?

Tags: html, css

What i want to get is the following image.

[image]

There are two divs. The inner div is at the center of the outer div, and text `box1` is at the center of inner div.

The css code can't achieve the target.

```
div.father {
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 300px;
}

div.son {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

<div class="father">
  <div class="son">box1</div>
</div>
```

[image]

How to put the `box1` at the center of div.son?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css

Comment: You don't need `position: absolute`, `top`, `left` or `transform`. You can nest flexboxes (i.e. make both `.father` and `.son` flex containers). Here's a simple method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Comment: See also Box #56 here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex box. [Here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/01kqdmt8/).

```css
div.father {
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /**/
  margin-top: 100px;/*only for snippet spacing*/
}
div.son {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <div class="son">box1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope will work.

```
div.son {
border: 1px solid black;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 100px;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is simple, just add `text-align: center` to any of the elements for horizontal alignment.

E.g.

```
div.son {
    ...
    text-align:center; /* horizontal align */
}
```

As for vertical alignment, if it is one word, you can use line-height like so:

```
div.son {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align:center; /* horizontal align */
    line-height:100px; /* vertical align */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/j1e9qoao/

```
div.father {
  display: flex;

    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 300px;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 300px;
}

div.son {
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: table-cell;
 border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: the text isn't in the middle like OP was asking for.

Comment: @leftside he was asking for vertically aligning the text in the middle. to center text horizontally  text-align: center

Comment: Check the question again: the first image.

Comment: In chrome it didn't work - unless it's changed. Not at my desktop now.

Answer (score -1):

You may try this one:

```
div.son {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 50px;
}
```